# Django Datepicker calculate age

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form that allows the user to set the date of birth via a datepicker. How can I calculate the age after the date is selected after the user selects the date in the web page?

Kind of stumped on how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This answers assume that you have imported datetime and time.

```
"How can I calculate the age after the date is selected?"
```

Here you go, it so simple.

Suppose his date of birth that is stored in database looks like this:

```
dob = datetime.datetime(1990, 4, 18, 11, 29, 25, 52392) # 18 Apr, 1990
```

Then dob in seconds is:

```
dob_sec = time.mktime(dob.timetuple())
```

Current time in seconds is:

```
c_time = time.time()
```

So total seconds lived is:

```
lived = c_time-dob_sec
```

Minutes lived:

```
min = lived/60
```

Hours lived:

```
hrs = min/60
```

Days Lived;

```
days = hrs/24
```

Years lived:

```
age_in_years = days/365
```

If you want it to show on the web page automatically, then use jquery something like this.
But before this, you need to add an id to your form

```
<form>
    ....
    <div id="show_age"></div>
<form>
```

and add a ajax call to you age calculation views in jquery. This view's html page should have an input hidden type like this.

```
<input type='hidden' name='age_in_years' value='{{age_in_years}}' />
```

where {{age_in_years}} will come from the age calculation views in context.

```
// I am not writing here the whole jquery code for you.
// You have to try it yourself...
$("#id_date_picker").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
         // You ajax call here
         // in data, pass the selected value that will act as a parameter to 
         //you django age calculation views.
         success: function(args) {
              var age_in_years = $("args input[name="age_in_years"].val();
              $("#show_age").html(age_in_years);
         }

    });

});
```

Comment: I am talking about showing that on my form after selecting a date. So basically after the user selects a date then the age field is filled in automagically.

Comment: Check your question, have you mention it anywhere that it should be shown automatically on the web  page form?? You just have asked how to calculate....

Comment: Yes I just changed it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Now check the update. It is not full answer as you should try it youself.

Comment: Yes I know its not a full answer, however I am not sure how I can know a date was selected on the form?

Comment: `$("#id_date_picker").change(function() {` this function do this for you, it keeps track of the changes on the selcting element if the element id is `id_date_picker`