# How do I calculate age using Django with a class-based form, templates and gijgo datepicker?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have read this post and I believe that mine in totally different; [Django Datepicker calculate age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120305/django-datepicker-calculate-age)

I am using Django version 4.0.1.  I am making use of the Gijgo datepicker to capture the date of birth of the person registering.  In my base.html template I added this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$('.dateinput').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });</script>
```

In my register.html template I extends the base template.  The form in the register template use a POST method. The code is:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
```

With a submit button.  The form I use is a class based form in my forms.py file.  The code for that looks like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from datetime import date

selection = [
('yes', 'Yes'),
('no', 'No')
]

class StudentApplicationForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
date_of_birth = forms.DateField()
previous_experience = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=selection))
terms_and_conditions = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'date_of_birth',
        'terms_and_conditions',
        'previous_experience',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
    ]


def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    email_count = User.objects.filter(email=email).count()

    if email_count > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email is already in use.  Please select a different email!')
    return email

def calc_age(self):
    dob = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
    raise forms.ValidationError(int(dob))

    return dob
```

The email function works.  For now, I just want to see what I get from the date_of_birth input, but I don't get anything on my screen.  See the image below.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error for the date of birth field when submitting the form or at all?

Comment: No, none what-so-ever.  I even tried this:     def calc_age(self):
        dob = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')

        today = date.today()
        age = int(today.year) - int(dob.year) - ((int(today.month), int(today.day)) < (int(dob.month), int(dob.day)))

        if int(age) < 18:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Too young!')
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Old enough!')

        return int(age)

Comment: Can you try setting the input format for the datefield in your form? Take a look here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats

Comment: @Mekicha I tried that and it;s not working either.

Answer (score 0):

This is working now.  The only problem is that the error message does not display correctly.`

```
    def clean_date_of_birth(self):
    date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
    dob = date_of_birth

    today = date.today()
    age = int(today.year) - int(dob.year) - ((int(today.month), int(today.day)) < (int(dob.month), int(dob.day)))

    if int(age) < 18:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Too young, parents must register you!')
    return date_of_birth
```

You have to use the method `clean_<valiable_name>`